# SQL Table Error Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento

This is very odd, anyone have an answer for why this gives an error?

```
 ------------------------------------------------------ --
--
 -- Table structure for table `mg_cataloginventory_stock`
--
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `mg_cataloginventory_stock` (

`stock_id` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'Stock Id',
`stock_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'Stock Name',
 PRIMARY KEY (  `stock_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'Cataloginventory Stock';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--------------------------------------------------------

--
 -- Table structu' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your [SQL comment syntax is incorrect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on).

It should be something like this:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `mg_cataloginventory_stock`
--
```